# Python functions and array parameters

Tags: python, arrays, database, numpy, 3d

I am trying to build a program that can produce (x,y,z) 10x10x10 arrays (unit cells) on a 3D grid. Example: one cube is at point (0,10)x(0,10)x(0,10) while another is at (0,10)x(10,20)x(0,10). So far I have a function that makes 4 of these but how would I automate it to make dozens or even hundreds?

```
import math
import numpy as np


def cubeplot():
    count = 0
    count2 = 0
    x = 11
    y = 11
    z = 11
    c = 11
    parameter = np.arange(0,11,1)
    xx, yy, zz = np.meshgrid(parameter, parameter, parameter)
    valuesrange = np.zeros((11, 11, 11))
    parameter2 = np.arange(c, y+10,1)
    xx2, yy2, zz2 = np.meshgrid(parameter2, parameter2, parameter2)
    valuesrange2 = np.zeros((x+10, y+10 , z + 10))
    parameter3 = np.arange(c + 10, y+20,1)
    xx2, yy2, zz2 = np.meshgrid(parameter2, parameter2, parameter2)
    valuesrange2 = np.zeros((x+20, y+20 , z +20))

    print('POINT 1')
    while (count < 1):
        xint = np.random.randint(0,2)
        yint = np.random.randint(0,2)
        zint = np.random.randint(0,2)

        if xint > 0:
            xint = np.random.randint(10,c, 22)
            x = 10
        else:
            xint = np.random.randint(0,1, 22)
            x = 0
        if yint >0:
            yint = np.random.randint(10,c, 22)  
            y = 10
        else: 
            yint = np.random.randint(0,1, 22)
            y = 0
        if zint > 0:
            zint = np.random.randint(10,c, 22)  
            z = 10
        else:
            zint = np.random.randint(0,1, 22)
            z = 0
        count = count + 1
        print('x = ' + str(x))
        print('y = ' + str(y))
        print('z = ' + str(z))
    #       print('Distance = ' + str(zint))

    print('POINT 2')

    while (count2 < 1):
        xint = np.random.randint(0,2)
        yint = np.random.randint(0,2)
        zint = np.random.randint(0,2)

        if xint > 0:
            xint = np.random.randint(20,c + 10, 22)  
            x2 = 20
        else:
            xint = np.random.randint(10,11, 22)
            x2 = 10
        if yint >0:
            yint = np.random.randint(10,c, 22)  
            y2 = 10
        else: 
            yint = np.random.randint(0,1, 22)
            y2 = 0
        if zint > 0:
            zint = np.random.randint(10,c, 22)  
            z2 = 10
        else:
            zint = np.random.randint(0,1, 22)
            z2 = 0
        count2 = count2 + 1
        print('x = ' + str(x2))
        print('y = ' + str(y2))
        print('z = ' + str(z2))

    distance = ((x2-x)**2 + (y2 - y)**2 + (z2 - z)**2)**.5   
    print ('POINT 1: x,y,z: ' + str(x) +',' + str(y) + ','+ str(z))
    print ('POINT 2: x,y,z: ' + str(x2) +',' + str(y2)+ ',' + str(z2))
    print('Distance = ' + str(distance))

    print('POINT 3')
    count3 = 0
    while (count3 < 1):
        xint = np.random.randint(0,2)
        yint = np.random.randint(0,2)
        zint = np.random.randint(0,2)

        if xint > 0:
           xint = np.random.randint(10,c, 22)  
           x3 = 10
        else:
            xint = np.random.randint(0,1, 22)
            x3 = 0
        if yint >0:
            yint = np.random.randint(10,c, 22)  
            y3 = 10
        else: 
            yint = np.random.randint(0,1, 22)
            y3 = 0
        if zint > 0:
            zint = np.random.randint(20,c + 10, 22)  
            z3 = 20
        else:
            zint = np.random.randint(10,c, 22)
            z3 = 10
        count3 = count3 + 1
        print('x = ' + str(x3))
        print('y = ' + str(y3))
        print('z = ' + str(z3))

    print('POINT 4')
    count4 = 0
    while (count4 < 1):
        xint = np.random.randint(0,2)
        yint = np.random.randint(0,2)
        zint = np.random.randint(0,2)

        if xint > 0:
            xint = np.random.randint(20,c+10, 22)  
            x4 = 20
        else:
            xint = np.random.randint(10,c, 22)
            x4 = 10
        if yint >0:
            yint = np.random.randint(10,c, 22)  
            y4 = 10
        else: 
            yint = np.random.randint(0,1, 22)
            y4 = 0
        if zint > 0:
            zint = np.random.randint(20,c + 10, 22)  
            z4 = 20
        else:
            zint = np.random.randint(10,c, 22)
            z4 = 10
        count4 = count4 + 1
        print('x = ' + str(x4))
        print('y = ' + str(y4))
        print('z = ' + str(z4))
        print ('POINT 3: x,y,z: ' + str(x3) +',' + str(y3) + ','+ str(z3))
        print ('POINT 4: x,y,z: ' + str(x4) +',' + str(y4)+ ',' + str(z4))
        print('SET END')
        print('')
        print('')
        print('')


runtime = int (input("How many times would you like to run the program?: "))
maincount = 0
print ('The program will run', runtime, 'times')

while (maincount < runtime):
    cubeplot()
    maincount = maincount + 1
```

Comment: You can start by showing us your code.

Comment: Put it in a loop?

Comment: Sorry forgot to add code.

Comment: For the loop I don't know how to keep changing the parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[numpy arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/arrays.ndarray.html) are a bit more powerful than you might think. If you want each cell of your 3D grid to have another 3D grid, what you are looking for is a 6D grid. Check the following example:

```
import numpy as np

# Lets make a 3D grid in which each cell has 3 dimensions
# (making it a 6D grid)
grid = np.zeros((3, 2, 4, 10, 10, 10))

# So for every arbitrary 3D coordinate of the grid I have
# another 3D grid (result: (10, 10, 10))
print(grid[2, 1, 3].shape)

# If a make a grid for a single cell:
# the randint function is creating a (10, 10, 10) grid
local_grid = np.random.randint(0, 10, (10, 10, 10))

# I can put it inside my big grid:
grid[2, 1, 3] = local_grid

# If I need to this for all (3, 2, 4) shape of my big grid
# (meaning its first 3 dimensions) I can loop each of those
# dimensions:
for x in range(grid.shape[0]):
    for y in range(grid.shape[1]):
        for z in range(grid.shape[2]):
            grid[x, y, z] = np.random.randint(0, 10, (10, 10, 10))
```

There are other ways to fill a grid (possibly more optimal) depending on your needs but there is little need for you to play with indexation numbers unless you really need to. Is this what you are looking for (logic wise)?

**EDIT:** So if you really want just a 3D grid you can multiply your cell dimensions by grid dimension and loop it to index some content inside. For example:

```
target = (3, 2, 4)
cell = (3, 3, 3)
grid = np.zeros((target[0]*cell[0], target[1]*cell[1], target[2]*cell[2]))
counter = 1
for x in range(target[0]):
    for y in range(target[1]):
        for z in range(target[2]):
            grid[x*cell[0]:x*cell[0]+cell[0], y*cell[0]:y*cell[1]+cell[1], z*cell[2]:z*cell[2]+cell[2]] = counter
            counter += 1
```

In this case `grid[0:cell[0], 0:cell[1], 0:cell[2]]` will be equal to a grid of `cell` dimensions whose content is `1`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Correct me if I'm wrong. The code above makes a large 3D grid and each cube is its own 3D grid. So far that is what I want. But how would I get this(small grids) to fill an arbitrary 3D grid (larger grids). A couple of questions what does the 3,2,4 mean for the big grid? and what does the 2,1,3 mean for the smaller grid? Is the bigger grid bigger by a magnitude of 1? Sorry for the confusion I am a complete novice.

Comment: @Astupidhippo I've edited the answer to provide you with an actual 3D grid. If you use a 3D grid but actually need to work in 6D you'll have to take care of the indexation positions. That is what is happening inside the loop in the EDIT.

Comment: Might be a dumb question. When you say 'grid = np.zeros ((3,2,4,10,10,10))' 3x2x4 is the small grid and 10x10x10 is the large grid, correct? 'print(grid[2, 1, 3].shape)' you just adjusted the dimensions of the smaller grid, right? I don't understand the use of the local_grid. What is it doing?

Comment: @Astupidhippo The (3, 2, 4) shape would be the big grid, and the (10, 10, 10) the cell. So for every coordinate in (3, 2, 4) you have a (10, 10, 10) cell. The local_grid variable is a cell grid. I was trying to exemplify the building of a cell (`np.random.randint(0, 10, (10, 10, 10)` creates a grid of shape (10, 10, 10) with a random value 0 to 10 [not inc.] in each of its elements) followed by its placing at any 3D coordinate of the big grid. The `shape` command only returns the number of elements in each direction, it does not change the grid in any way.